# How to add an ISAPI extension to a ASP.Net development iis server?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis

Because of a CMS software that I'm using I need to add a ".*" ISAPI extension to my IIS (pointing to aspnet_isapi.dll).

What I would like to do is to have the ability to add a ISAPI extension to my VS IIS server as well, so that I can test my webapp locally instead of deploying it to the server all the time.

Is it possible to achieve that in the VS embedded IIS server (I'm using VS 2008)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible, but all requests are routed to asp.net by default, so it should work out of the box.

Comment: That's what I expected, but instead it does a directory browsing on my root.
Is it possible to disable directory browsing???

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET development server doesn't support ISAPI extensions. Your best bet is probably to install IIS on your development machine and add the ISAPI extension there. If you're using XP you should have IIS as long as you're running professional. I think with Vista you need a business edition or above.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think it is possible. Cassini is not actually IIS, it is more of an emulation. It doesn't have all of the features that you will find in the full IIS.